# Перевод целых чисел в бинарную систему счисления

Tags: c++, файлы, binary, filestream

Требуется создать и заполнить 15-ю числами 2 бинарных файла, а в 3 бинарный файл занести сумму четных чисел из этих 2 файлов. Помогите, пожалуйста.

1. Не получается реализовать функцию `void findEvenSumBin();`, для нахождения суммы.
2. В бинарных файлах находятся значения в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления, как изменить на двоичную?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void createAndFillBin(int numbers_1, int numbers_2);
void findEvenSumBin(int numbers_1, int numbers_2);

int main() {
    int numbers_1 = 0;
    int numbers_2 = 0;
    createAndFillBin(numbers_1, numbers_2);
    findEvenSumBin(numbers_1, numbers_2);
    return 0;
}

void createAndFillBin(int numbers_1, int numbers_2) {
    //creating binary files and filling them with numbers from 0 to 30
    ofstream file_1("file_1.bin", ios_base::binary);
    ofstream file_2("file_2.bin", ios_base::binary);
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        numbers_1 = rand() % 31;
        file_1.write((char*)&numbers_1, sizeof(numbers_1));
        numbers_2 = rand() % 31;
        file_2.write((char*)&numbers_2, sizeof(numbers_2));
    }
    file_1.close();
    file_2.close();
}

void findEvenSumBin(int numbers_1, int numbers_2) {
    //finding sum of even elements in 2 binary files, then writing sum into 3rd file
    ifstream file_1("file_1.bin", ios_base::binary);
    ifstream file_2("file_2.bin", ios_base::binary);
    int sum = 0;
    if (file_1.is_open() && file_2.is_open()) {
        while (file_1 >> numbers_1)
            if (numbers_1 % 2 == 0)
                sum += numbers_1;
        while (file_2 >> numbers_2)
            if (numbers_2 % 2 == 0)
                sum += numbers_2;
        file_1.close();
        file_2.close();
        ofstream file_3("file_3.bin", ios_base::binary);
        file_3.write((char*)&sum, sizeof(sum));
        file_3.close();
        cout << "All files was created! Check them in the folder." << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error with opening files." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, смотрите сами, что не так, как у вас.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void createAndFillBin();
void findEvenSumBin();

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    createAndFillBin();
    findEvenSumBin();
    return 0;
}

void createAndFillBin()
{
    //creating binary files and filling them with numbers from 0 to 30
    ofstream file_1("file_1.bin", ios_base::binary);
    ofstream file_2("file_2.bin", ios_base::binary);
    for (int n, i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        n = rand() % 31;
        file_1.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        n = rand() % 31;
        file_2.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
    }
}

void findEvenSumBin()
{
    //finding sum of even elements in 2 binary files, then writing sum into 3rd file
    ifstream file_1("file_1.bin", ios_base::binary);
    ifstream file_2("file_2.bin", ios_base::binary);
    int sum = 0, n;
    if (file_1.is_open() && file_2.is_open())
    {
        while(file_1.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n)))
              if (n%2 == 0) sum += n;
        while(file_2.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n)))
              if (n%2 == 0) sum += n;
        ofstream file_3("file_3.bin", ios_base::binary);
        file_3.write((char*)&sum, sizeof(sum));
        cout << "All files was created! Check them in the folder." << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Error with opening files." << endl;
}
```

Или даже так:

```
void createAndFillBin(const char * fname);
int findEvenSumBin(const char * fname);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    createAndFillBin("file_1.bin");
    createAndFillBin("file_2.bin");
    int sum = findEvenSumBin("file_1.bin") + findEvenSumBin("file_2.bin");
    ofstream file_3("file_3.bin", ios_base::binary);
    file_3.write((char*)&sum, sizeof(sum));
    cout << "All files was created! Check them in the folder." << endl;
}

void createAndFillBin(const char * fname)
{
    //creating binary files and filling them with numbers from 0 to 30
    ofstream file(fname, ios_base::binary);
    for (int n, i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        n = rand() % 31;
        file.write((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
    }
}

int findEvenSumBin(const char * fname)
{
    //finding sum of even elements in 2 binary files, then writing sum into 3rd file
    ifstream file(fname, ios_base::binary);
    int sum = 0, n;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while(file.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n))) if (n%2 == 0) sum += n;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file." << endl;
        abort();
    }
    return sum;
}
```